# Get random value from JSON using ONLY parse and Math.random WITHOUT loops, arrays and Object.keys

Tags: javascript, json, object, math, random

I have got a JSON:

```
let jsonName  = '{"name1": "John", "name2": "Billy", "name3": "Tristan"}';
let jsonSurname  = '{ "surname1": "Doe", "surname2": "Smith", "surname3": "Dodson"}';
```

I need to get random value from both jsonName, jsonSurname (for example "John" and "Doe") and parse this two values into one object.
I must to use Math.random. **There can't be** loops, arrays, Object.keys, Object.entries, Object.values, Object.getOwnPropertyNames.

I think that i must to use parse somehow for both properties:

```
JSON.parse(jsonName, function (key, value) { 

 // SOME MAGIC with Math.random

  });
```

Help me please!

Comment: Do you know in advance how many entries you'll have? If not, is it OK to parse them _twice_? Because you could first decide the how-manyth entry you will use (using the number of entries and `Math.random`) and then count a variable up in your callback and save the value if the counter matches the preselected index. If you don't know the number of keys in advance, you can parse it twice, and the first time just count up to get the total number of entries. (And do the whole thing for both name and surname, of course.)

Comment: 1 = why these constraints?, 2 = you are supposed to provide your code, not that we do your job

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: Hi Katelyn. Can I help you with understanding the concepts of this community?

Comment: Let me explain why I undid your last edit to the title. You are asking for code with specific restraints. But you don't provide reasoning for those restraints and do not really show any attempt of doing this yourself. This is why your question as it is does not really fit the idea of StackOverflow. Also the lack of explanation of (very typical and otherwise weird restraints, in combinitation with lack of own attempts, gives the impression of being an attempt to have your homework done by others. Compare https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Only removing the restraint from the title, but keeping them in the body, still without explanation, is not helpful. Please keep the restraints and explain their reasons (removing them from the title then would make it more readable, but not as a stanalone edit). Generally, please focus this question on the specific programming problem you encountered while trying this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that every property in `jsonName` starts with `name` followed by a number, you could use string literals to access a specific property.

Example:

```js
const data = {
  name1: 'vitor',
  name2: 'roberto',
  name3: 'joao'
}

console.log(data[`name${1}`]) // output: 'vitor'
```

With that, all you have to do is use `Math.random()` to generate the random number.

For example, to generate a random number from 1 to 10, you could use:

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
```

Assign it to a variable:

```js
const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 1
```

Then use it in the string literal:

```js
console.log(data[`name${randomNumber}`])
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this was a fun challenge!

The restrictions pose a few major obstacles. A double-lookup is absolutely unavoidable because you need to know the **number of possible names** which is unavailable until the object has finished parsing - and because arrays, Object.keys, etc, are not allowed, you can't then look up the answer.

I've made a few assumptions here:

- We don't already know the number of entries
- We can't depend on the keys being in the same format and reliable (name1, name2, etc)
- We want to avoid manually parsing the json strings, and avoid parsing them twice

First thought: The obvious answer is to parse the data twice. But this is ugh.

Next thought: The approach says that arrays are not allowed, but strings are technically arrays - this could be abused in order to cheat an answer.

But wait.. we can't use arrays, but we can use objects - and with implicit type coersion, objects can be accessed with numeric indices.

So let's go.

```
const jsonName  = '{"name1": "John", "name2": "Billy", "name3": "Tristan"}';
const jsonSurname  = '{ "surname1": "Doe", "surname2": "Smith", "surname3": "Dodson"}';

function pick(source, callback)
{
    let chosen;
    const tempObject = {};
    let count = 0;
    JSON.parse(source, function (key, value)
    {
        if (typeof value === 'object')
        {
            return callback(chosen);
        }

        tempObject[count] = value;
        count++;
        chosen = tempObject[Math.floor(Math.random() * count)];
    });
}


pick(jsonName, (firstName) => {
    pick(jsonSurname, (lastName) => {
        const result = { 'name': firstName, 'surname': lastName};
        console.log(result);
    });
})
```

Of course, JSON.parse itself invokes several loops, but I guess this is OK.